# Translating a 2D Array to nested dictonary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, openpyxl

I'm working with openpyxl to read and write xlsx files, for some data manipulation purposes I need to translate my worksheet (which I have represented in a 2D matrix) into a dictionary which follows a specific format, here is my matrix.

```
[['Name', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Height', 'Hair Color'],
 ['Jay', '12', 'M', '123cm', 'Black'],
 ['Marie', '13', 'F', '100cm', 'Red'],
 ['Dan', '16', 'M', '200cm', 'Brown']
]
```

I'd like to translate this so that the resulting dictionary looks like:

```
{

{ 'Jay;12;M' : 'Name': 'Jay', 'Age': '12', 'Gender': 'M', 'Height': '123cm', 'Hair Color' : 'Black'}, 

{ 'Marie;13;F' : 'Name': 'Marie', 'Age': '13', 'Gender': 'F', 'Height': '100cm', 'Hair Color' : 'Red'},

{ 'Dan;16;M' : 'Name': 'Dan', 'Age': '16', 'Gender': 'M', 'Height': '200cm', 'Hair Color' : 'Brown'},

}
```

I'm relatively new to Python and I believe a dictionary comprehension is the way to go but I'm not exactly sure how to get these 2D array values by name so I can build my key value pairs properly.

Comment: The 2D array has no names, you need to address the contents by providing numerical index values to pick the wanted array and its wanted element.

Comment: You can do something like this `my_dict[my_array[0][y]] = my_array[x][y]` inside a loop. Also, just fyi, typo in your dictionary. should look like `'Jay;12;M' : {'Name': 'Jay', 'Age': '12' ...` etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want this format:

`{'<name>;<age>;<gender>': {'Name': <name>, 'Age': <age>, 'Gender': <gender>, 'Height': <height>: 'Hair Color': <hair_color>}}`

Having:

- `l`: your multidimensional array
- `k`: first row (keys)

Try this:

```
{reduce(lambda x, y : '{0};{1}'.format(x,y), l[j]):{k[i]: l[j][i] for i in range(len(k))} for j in range(1, len(l))}
```

This *list comprehension* iterates through all the rows of `l` (except the first one) and for each one, creates a dictionary whose keys are the elements of `k` and the values are the elements of the current `l`'s row.

**UPDATE**

You can pass another iterable to `reduce` function instead of `l[j]` (the complete row). For your case could be: `l[j][:3]` instead of `l[j]`, see the use of [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).
So the above should have: `reduce(lambda x, y : '{0};{1}'.format(x,y), l[j][:3])`.

Also, the use of [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) can make a little bit more elegant the creation of the inner dictionaries:

```
r = {reduce(lambda x, y : '{0};{1}'.format(x,y), l[j][:3]):{t[0]: t[1] for t in zip(k, l[j])} for j in range(1, len(l))}
```

Comment: This definitely works but it gives me a key that consists of all the values, I only need it for 3 specific values in the dictionary, so I'll tweak this a bit more to make it work, thanks.